# Solving the initial value Problem $x'=f(x)$ where $f(x)=(-x_1,-x_2+x_1^2,x_3+x_1^2)^T$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following initial value problem.

$$x'=f(x)$$
$$x(0)=y$$

For $f(x)=(-x_1,-x_2+x_1^2,x_3+x_1^2)^T$.

since $ {dx_1 \over dt} =-x_1$, we get $x_1=y_1e^{-t}$, but I don't know how to find $x_2$ and $x_3$. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}x_1'&=-x_1 &(1)\\ x_2'&=-x_2+x_1^2 &(2)\\ x_3'&=x_3+x_1^2 &(3)  \end{cases}$$

As you noticed correctly one has to solve (1) at the beginning and one gets

$$x_1=y_1 e^{-t}$$

Now we plug this into our equation system:

$$\begin{cases}x_2'&=-x_2+y_1^2e^{-2t} &(2) \\ x_3'&=x_3+y_1^2e^{-2t} &(3) \end{cases}$$

Now solve (2) to get $x_2$ and (3) to get $x_3$. These are just some linear non-homogenous ODEs and not hard to solve. They have some basic solution theory. I show you one way how to solve (2).

\begin{align}x_2'+x_2&=y_1^2e^{-2t} \\ \Rightarrow e^tx_2'+e^tx_2&=y_1^2e^{-t} \\ \Rightarrow(e^tx_2)'&=y_1^2e^{-t} \\\Rightarrow e^tx_2&=\int y_1^2e^{-t}=-y_1^2 e^{-t}+c \\ \Rightarrow x_2&=e^{-2t}(-y_1^2+ce^{t}) \end{align}

Additionally you can now plug in your initial condition $x_2(0)=y_2$ to determine $c$. (3) works in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You are left with two non-homogeneous ODEs,
$$
\frac{dx_2}{dt} = -x_2 + y_1^2 e^{-2t}, \qquad 
\frac{dx_3}{dt} = x_3 + y_1^2e^{-2t}.
$$
Since these are very similar I will just examine the $x_2$ dynamics. This can be handled using variation of parameters or an integrating factor. I prefer to use variation of parameters since I feel it is more powerful and requires remembering less, but it's up to the individual's preference. First notice that without the forcing term we have the ODE
$$
\frac{d x_2}{dt} = -x_2
$$
with general solution $x_2(t) = C e^{-t}$. Using variation of parameters we let $C$ now be a function of $t$, i.e. $x_2(t) = C(t) e^{-t}$. Then
$$
\frac{dx_2}{dt} = C'(t) e^{-t} - C(t) e^{-t} = -x_2 + y_1^2 e^{-2t} = -C(t)e^{-t} + y_1^2 e^{-2t}.
$$
This gives an ODE for $C'(t)$
$$
C'(t) = - y_1^2 e^{-2t}.
$$
You can simplify integrate this ODE to get $C(t) = \frac{y_1^2}{2} e^{-2t}+c$. Now you have 
$$
x_2(t) = \left(\frac{y_1^2}{2} e^{-2t}+c\right)e^{-t}.
$$
Plug in at $x=0$ to find $c$ in terms of $y_2$ and then do the same with $x_3$!